# UIImagePickerController not respecting video maximum duration on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to build an app that would let user pick and upload a video from the library on iPad. I need the max video length to be 30 sec.

I am using the following code:

```
UIImagePickerController *mediaPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

mediaPicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie,(NSString *)kUTTypeImage,nil];
mediaPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

mediaPicker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame960x540;
mediaPicker.videoMaximumDuration = 30.0f;
mediaPicker.delegate = self;


if (self.imagePickerPopOverController.popoverVisible) {
    [self.imagePickerPopOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

self.imagePickerPopOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:mediaPicker];
[self.imagePickerPopOverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
                                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                                          animated:NO];
```

After the video has been picked, I expect the UIImagePickerController to show a trimmer to trim the video length to 30 sec (if its longer), but it does not.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set this before you present the controller.

```
imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! That worked. Just curious, how come it works on iPhone without allowsEditing set to YES but not on iPad?