# UIImagePickerController videoMaximumDuration not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, xcode8

I'm taking `video` from camera and after choosing video just checking the video duration in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method, if the video duration is less then 15 sec dismiss the `UIImagePickerController` and starting to use the video, but the video duration is more then 15 sec justing showing alert to crop the video. here I’m not dismissing the `UIImagePickerController` just showing alert after alert dismissed the `UIImagePickerController` not actionable its disabled like (retake & play and user video) buttons are disabled.

```
    imageController.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]
    imageController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
    imageController.allowsEditing = true
    self.present(imageController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
    {
               let outputFileURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! URL
               let asset = AVURLAsset(url: outputFileURL)
               let durationInSeconds = asset.duration.seconds

        if(durationInSeconds < 15)
             {
                // Here my upload process
             }
               else {
                   Constants.showErrorAlertView(message: "15 seconds only allowed please trim the video and upload ")
               }
     }
```

Comment: the answer to this question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17375309/4833705

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what `"public.movie"` means but the problem might possibly be in the `.mediaTypes`

See [Apple: videoMaximumDuration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/1619146-videomaximumduration)

> This property is available only if the mediaTypes property’s value
>   array includes the kUTTypeMovie media type.

Your using: `imageController.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]`

Try using: `imageController.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]`

Be sure to add `MobileCoreServices` to your header file to be able to use the `kUTTypeMovie`:

```
#import MobileCoreServices
```

Comment: Thank you, but my actual problems is while receiving the video in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method just checking the duration  if the duration is exceeding 15 seconds camera i'm not closing the UIImagePickerController  without closing just showing the  alert to  trim the video and try again. after alert dismissed UIImagePickerController buttons not actionable, this is my problem.

Comment: So the problem is if the video is more then 15 secs, an alert is shown, and after the alert is dismissed and the imagePicker is dismissed your buttons no longer receive touch events?

Comment: No, i'm not dismissing the imagePicker, if the duration is less than 15 seconds then only dismissing the imagePicker, if not showing alert only not dismissing  imagePicker.

Comment: If a video is more then 15 secs, after the alert is shown, what happens to the imagePicker after you dismiss the alert? I don’t understand what the exact problem is. I don’t think I can help because I don’t understand the issue. Good luck coding hope you fix it! 